# MSMQ Connection Cache Security Vulnerability?

Tags: c#, msmq

When working with MSMQ, the connection cache is disabled by default. Enabling the MSMQ connection cache increases queue throughput significantly (~10x).

While reviewing the [code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Messaging/System/Messaging/MessageQueue.cs) there is a reference to a security vulnerability as highlighted below.

```
// Whidbey Beta 2 SECREVIEW (Dec 2004 [....]):
// Connection Cache can be a security vulnerability (see bug 422227)
// Therefore, disable it by default
private static bool enableConnectionCache = false;
```

What is the potential security vulnerability (unable to locate bug reference)?

Answer (score 0):

One explanation could be that there is a potential memory leak associated with using the cache as Dispose() doesn't close the queue handle. See section 18.9 of the [MSMQ FAQ](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/9/FC9989A2-DA75-4D96-B654-4BD29CF6AEE1/MSMQ_faq_updated.doc).